# How to debug typos in $(...) selection?

Tags: jquery

```
$ = (function($_) {
    'use strict'
    var $ = function () {
        var result = $_.apply(this, arguments)
        if (result.length === 0)
            console.log(
                '$.call(' + this + ', ' +
                JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)) +
                ') returned empty selection!'
            )
        return result
    }
    Object.assign($, $_)
    return $
})($)
```

When in my code `$(...)` selection does not match anything, it usually means that I made a typo.

The code above replaces jQuery's `$` function with one written by me, which writes message in console in case nothing matched to help me find the bug.

I know I could check using `$(...).length`, but I'd have to insert it everywhere.

**Is there better (maybe built-in) way of debugging typos in `$(...)` selection?

(especially ones that make it match nothing)**

Comment: Note: `console.debug()` can be used instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: This seems like overkill for a simple problem of just taking more care when coding

Answer (score 1):

add this plugin:

```
$.fn.ensure = function(){
  if (this.length)
     return this;
}
```

see the result
[image]